# How to change localhost to some other name in JBOSS EAP 6.3?

Tags: jboss6.x

Currently, my service is running on http://localhost:8080/MyService/. I want to change localhost to service.example.com - http://service.example.com:8080/MyService/. I updated standalone-full.xml with the new alias.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" />
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="service.example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

But it did not work. I am getting "This Webpage is not available" message. Please suggest.

**Update**:
Changed jboss-web.xml as above. When deploy my war file, I am getting 404 error.

jboss-web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-web>
        <security-domain>java:/jaas/EmpMem</security-domain>
        <context-root>/</context-root>
        <virtual-host>service.example.com</virtual-host>
    </jboss-web>
```

standalone-full.xml

**Server Log:**

```
16:09:21,705 ERROR [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception during createSubject()JBAS013303: Runtime Exception:: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS013303: Runtime Exception:
    at org.jboss.as.security.plugins.ModuleClassLoaderLocator.get(ModuleClassLoaderLocator.java:56)
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:317)
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.createSubject(JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.java:83)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer$1.run(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1078)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer$1.run(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1073)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.createSubject(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1072)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.deployDataSource(AbstractDsDeployer.java:600)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractDsDeployer.java:282)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer.deploy(AbstractDataSourceService.java:316)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService.start(AbstractDataSourceService.java:120)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.usaa.loginmodule:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:240) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.security.plugins.SecurityActions.getModuleClassLoader(SecurityActions.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.security.plugins.ModuleClassLoaderLocator.get(ModuleClassLoaderLocator.java:47)
    ... 16 more

16:09:21,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/usecom_sau]
16:09:21,734 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221013: Using NIO Journal
16:09:21,911 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
16:09:21,912 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
16:09:21,917 WARN  [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-4) Warning - unknown codeset (Cp1252) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
16:09:21,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
16:09:22,009 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBAS018210: Register web context: /JBOSSWAR
16:09:22,035 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
16:09:22,083 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:22,110 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:22,163 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900 1.1.23 (redhat)
16:09:22,170 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:22,352 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.9.Final-redhat-1-4cc400c 127.0.0.1:5455 for CORE protocol
16:09:22,354 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.9.Final-redhat-1-4cc400c 127.0.0.1:5445 for CORE protocol
16:09:22,355 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221007: Server is now live
16:09:22,356 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.3.20.Final (2.3.20, 123) [43f01d80-b3cb-11e4-a1e5-0d8484f2438a] 
16:09:22,371 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
16:09:22,372 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.fooQueue
16:09:22,376 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/foo
16:09:22,377 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/foo
16:09:22,378 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
16:09:22,414 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
16:09:22,445 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-6) HornetQ resource adaptor started
16:09:22,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-6) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
16:09:22,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
16:09:22,594 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1936) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:794)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:353)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
    at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1704) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2000(ServiceControllerImpl.java:52) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1949) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1908) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more

16:09:22,630 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "JBOSSEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "JBOSSEAR.ear")
16:09:22,630 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war" (runtime-name : "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war")
16:09:22,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./: Failed to start service

16:09:22,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:09:22,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:09:22,718 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 3347ms - Started 360 of 399 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 75 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
16:09:27,677 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:27,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war (runtime-name: ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war) in 14ms
16:09:27,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war" (runtime-name: "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war")
16:09:27,759 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./.realm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./

16:09:42,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war.dodeploy
16:09:42,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war" (runtime-name: "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war")
16:09:42,834 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:42,841 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:42,843 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:42,889 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1936) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:794)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:353)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
    at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1704) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2000(ServiceControllerImpl.java:52) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1949) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1908) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more

16:09:42,893 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.\"emp.example.com\"./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.\"emp.example.com\"./: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists"}}
16:09:42,894 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war
16:09:42,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war (runtime-name: ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war) in 4ms
16:09:42,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ent_securityprefs_empMemService.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./.realm (no longer required)
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment."emp.example.com"./
```

Comment: I am not sure if you all can see my updated standalone-full.xml file above. I can onyl see upto standalone-full.xml line. So posting the updated content here:

Comment: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
            </virtual-server>
            <virtual-server name="empHost" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="service.example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
 </subsystem>

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify an appropriate virtual-host definition in your jboss-web.xml descriptor.

```
 <jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <virtual-host>www.mydot.com</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

[Click here to read more](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch07.html#ch9.virtualhost.ex)

Comment: Changed jboss-web.xml as above. When deploy my war file, I am getting 404 error. Added updated jboss-web.xml and standlaone-full.xml files above.

Comment: If i am not wrong  you need to change to

virtual-server name="service.example.com"

Comment: Changed virtual-server name="empHost" to virtual-server name="service.example.com" with the same error. When I try to open th page http://emp.example.com:8080/MyService/, I am getting "This page cannot be displayed" error.